# What are the exact rewards from the mission "Priority - Eden Prime"

Tags: mass-effect-3

After I finished the mission and spoke with Javik, I remember there were three "popups" with rewards from it. One was the assault rifle and another one a biotic power. But I forgot what was the last reward, I only remember it had the "Information" header in the popup.

I tried to load a save and finish the mission again but only got one "popup" with the assault rifle reward.

Comment: IGN's video walkthrough just shows two: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9kXbkNB5Uk

Comment: It was probably either a new upgrade from glyph or just some credits from the alliance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exact reward for this mission is, obviously reputation for talking to someone new. More notably is the Slam Power unlocked for your purchase in the medical bay and the Particle Rifle. There is no third reward that i could find in my research.

[Proof](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eSx3ylMlOms)